# Sorting Array of Objects based on Index in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have the following array of unique IDs:

```
idArray = ["56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"]
```

And I have another array of objects:

```
stories = [{"title": Story2, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7"},
{"title": Story4, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"},
{"title": Story1, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802"},
{"title": Story3, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805"}]
```

How can I sort the second array based on the index of the first array? Preferably using lodash, as the arrays can grow a bit larger.

So far, I have the following to get the indexes from the first array:

```
var sortArray = _.toPairs(idArray)

[ [ '0', 56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802 ],
[ '1', 56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7 ],
[ '2', 56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805 ],
[ '3', 56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac ] ]
```

Trying different combinations of _.map() and _.sortBy() I can't seem to properly get the result I want which is:

```
desiredResult = [{"title": Story1, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802"},
          {"title": Story2, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7"},
          {"title": Story3, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805"},
          {"title": Story4, id = "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the sort solution is very ineffective especially since you expect the arrays to grow bigger later. Sort is "at best" an O(2n) operation while you have two indexOf operations per cycle another O(2n^2). I propose the following which will outperform the sort method in large arrays.

```js
var stories = [{"title": 'Story2', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7"},
{"title": 'Story4', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"},
{"title": 'Story1', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802"},
{"title": 'Story3', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805"}],

    idArray = ["56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"],

ordered = idArray.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(stories.find(f => f.id == c)) ,[]);

console.log(ordered);
```

Only O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

This is possible to do without any library using `Array.sort()`

```js
var stories = [{"title": 'Story2', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7"},
{"title": 'Story4', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"},
{"title": 'Story1', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802"},
{"title": 'Story3', id : "56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805"}];

var idArray = ["56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf802",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7b7",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf805",
"56f4cf96dd2ca7275feaf7ac"];

var ordered = stories.sort(function(a, b){
 return idArray.indexOf(a.id) - idArray.indexOf(b.id);
});

ordered.forEach( element =>{ console.log(element) });
```

Comment: Exactly my thought. You beat me to it... Here, have a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jx3we8q7/ ;)

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Is it ok to do 'return idArray.indexOf(b.id) - dArray.indexOf(a.id)' to reverse the order? Or should I use reverse() on the resulting array?

Comment: I think there's nothing bad to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var idsToIndexes = {};

for (var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++)
    idsToIndexes[idArray[i]] = i;

stories.sort(function(a, b){return idsToIndexes[a.id] - idsToIndexes[b.id];});
```